# Dropping metrics from the kubernetes-service-endpoints job in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I'm using the [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) chart and I'm trying to get rid of all the `kube_secret` metrics.

When I query these metrics I see that they originate from a job named `kubernetes-service-endpoints`, but I can't figure out what service monitor controls it in [`values.yaml`](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml), so I tried dropping them from every single configurable service monitor - in each one of them I put:

```yaml
    metricRelabelings:
    - action: drop
      regex: 'kube_secret_.+'
      sourceLabels: [__name__]
```

Didn't help of course. What do I need to define in `values.yaml` in order to drop those metrics?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm silly - I defined the `kubernetes-service-endpoints` job in `prometheus.prometheusSpec.additionalScrapeConfigs`...

In order to remove all `kube_secret` metrics I dropped metric names that matched `kube_secret_.+` for this job and in the service monitor of `kubeStateMetrics` (`kubeStateMetrics.serviceMonitor.metricRelabelings`)

Comment: You are not silly at all, and very good that you posted the answer.